# Remote desktop login over the internet

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

We had this windows 2008 R2 server up and running for more than a year....users were able to do remote login through RDC even over the internet.

About 2 days back we asked our computer person to upgrade the RAM...the RAM didnt fit as it was diff configuration ... so he replaced the old one back

Now i have these issues

1. All users except admin users have been locked down...i am unable to even login locally
2. So i reset the password
3. Now they are able to login trhough locally and also through RDC..but only from local network, they are ubale to login through RDC over the internet...it gives username/password mismatch/not found error

Can anyone help me out as to where the problem could be ??

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Replacing RAM would not do something like that. Something else must have happened.

Comment: Yes...but i am not sure what happened....why would all the users get locked out and need password reset...even then i am unable to login over internet...it gets connected but fails to login

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but I'm sorry I have to ask it... Did he shutdown the server before replacing the RAM?

Comment: Obviously he did....

Comment: Then he would have had to have done something else. Did anything else in the network change. The firewall perhaps?

Comment: None...i checked it..the OS is as it is...and he claims he did nothing...i will have to once again check every setting possible and see if i find anything else...i will update it in a day or two